# No implementation file was provicded for the .winmd file

Tags: c#, windows-8, bing-maps

I have a warning when I build my Windows 8 App project in VS2012:

```
No implementation file was provided for the .winmd file 'C:\Users\luke\LApp\LApp\bin\x86\Debug\Bing.Maps.winmd'. To generate registration information in the app manifest, specify the 'Implementation' metadata on the .winmd reference item in the project file.
```

I don't really know what other information to provide. I've Googled and it doesn't provide any relevant results. It gives a link to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708954.aspx but I'm not sure it is the correct thing. I'm pretty sure I have the correct references:

[image]

It is a C# project. I used NuGet to add the Bing Maps SDK and it works in my app - I can drag on a map interface and use it in the app. This is just a warning that shows up when building and I have no idea how to get rid of it.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is your project a c# project?

Usually WinRT components implemented using .NET are just .winmd files.  Both interface and implementation are contained within the .winmd file.  Whereas native components (those written in C++) will have separate .winmd and .dll files for interface and implementation respectively.

It would be helpful if you could provide more details about your app project and the repro steps.

Comment: Yes it is a C# project. I used NuGet to add the Bing Maps SDK and it works in my app - I can drag on a map interface and use it in the app. This is just a warning that shows up when building and I have no idea how to get rid of it.