# missing implementation for winmd

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Trying to add BouncyCastle c# dll to my WP8 native app.

- I create a Windows Runtime Component for Windows Phone 8
- I warp an existing C# dll in the component and create MyBouncyCastleComponent.winmd
- I open my WP8 native project and I add the winmd as a reference

Result: 
*At compile time* **"warning: No implementation file was provided for the .winmd file"**

*At runtime* it crashes and when I stop the emulator I got **"WinRT information: Class not registered"** (its much longer than that, complaining about missing PDB file's in window files like Windows.winmd and System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll)

I opened the winmd with ILDASM.
The implementations of decrypt and encrypt are there? What am I doing wrong?

[image: MyBouncyCastleComponent.winmd opened with ildasm]

I know its been asked [No implementation file was provicded for the .winmd file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895517/no-implementation-file-was-provicded-for-the-winmd-file) but there is no answer yet. I'm trying again... (couldn't figure out how to add it as a question there)

**EDIT:**
Just a clarification. when I say: "*I warp an existing C# dll in the component and create MyBouncyCastleComponent.winmd*"
what I did was take BouncyCastle **source** code put it in the runtime component with a wrapper class to expose the BouncyCastle methods I needed.

Comment: No, the .winmd file only contains *declarations*, not the implementation.  This is a packaging problem, for one, WinRT needs to know that the code is actually implemented in a language that requires the CLR to be loaded.  That requires a *manifest* that contains the `<clrClass>` element.  And the package needs to include the assembly.  Whether the CLR on a phone even supports this is a bit of a long shot.

Comment: As you discovered, warping may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It very much looks like you're jumping through hoops to try and get a C# DLL compiled for the full .NET framework to work on Windows Phone. Windows Phone uses a different .NET profile and isn't binary compatible with the full .NET framework, so this cannot work.

For BouncyCastle you will need to reference a binary DLL built specifically for Windows Phone - for example by building one yourself from the BouncyCastle source code.

UPDATE:
As you're using a subset of BouncyCastle you may be able to put the source code you need inside a Portable Class Library project so it can be directly used in both Windows Phone and Windows Store apps.

Comment: I think I did what you are saying. I used c# windows store/windows runtime component template. Added all the BouncyCastle c# source files and created the .winmd I have read every post I could find and  I'm totally stumped. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should use a normal .NET class library, Windows Phone doesn't support .NET WinRT components, only C++ ones.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me! I realized I must have missed something really trivial. WP8 can use a winRT component in C++ for c# but not in the opposite direction, like I need. So much for all the hoo haa about native and managed working seamlessly together. Disappointing. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714080%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: In this case you're just asking .NET and .NET to live together seamlessly - which they do with certain caveats such as binary compatibility between platforms.